# Ambiguous column - Laravel 5.1

Tags: banco-de-dados, laravel, postgresql, laravel-5

Bom dia! É o seguinte... tenho essas 2 tabelas no meu banco postgresql:

```
tipos_risco
--id
--nome

agentes_risco
--id
--nome
--id_tipo_risco (foreign key)
```

O problema é que não estou conseguindo extrair os dados delas juntas, pois ambas tem as colunas `id` e `nome`, ai da esse erro quando eu faço uma busca:

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 651:
SQLSTATE[42702]: Ambiguous column: 7 ERROR: column reference "nome" is ambiguous
LINE 1: ...sco"."id" = "agentes_risco"."id_tipo_risco" where "nome" ILI...
^ (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from "agentes_risco" left join "tipos_risco" on "tipos_risco"."id" = "agentes_risco"."id_tipo_risco" where "nome" ILIKE %frio%)
```

e esse:

```
PDOException in Connection.php line 321:
SQLSTATE[42702]: Ambiguous column: 7 ERROR: column reference "nome" is ambiguous
LINE 1: ...sco"."id" = "agentes_risco"."id_tipo_risco" where "nome" ILI...
```

essa é a query da minha função de busca:

```
return DB::table('agentes_risco')
                ->leftJoin('tipos_risco', 'tipos_risco.id', '=', 'agentes_risco.id_tipo_risco')
                ->where('nome', 'ILIKE', '%'.$busca.'%')
                ->select('agentes_risco.*','tipos_risco.*')
                ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
                ->paginate(10);
```

como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema está na ordenação, ambas as tabelas tem um campo chamado `id`, então especifique por qual id deverá ser ordenado, o mesmo se aplica para o campo `nome` lá na cláusula `like`.

```
->orderBy('id', 'asc') // errado
->where('nome', 'ILIKE', '%'.$busca.'%') //errado
```

Faça:

```
->orderBy('tipos_risco.id', 'asc')
->where('tipos_risco.nome', 'ILIKE', '%'.$busca.'%')
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @rray, isso funcionou. Agora consegui usar inclusive o "as" para alterar o nome da coluna na query para mostrar na view, coisa que não tinha funcionado anteriormente.